# Sl_log table is huge, over 100 million rows

Tags: postgresql, slony

We have slony replication set up, and the replication on the slave has fallen behind by 10 days.
On investigating I noticed that the sl_log_1 table has 25K records, but the sl_log_2 table has over 100 million rows, and they keep going up.
How do I go about troubleshooting this?

I am a newbie to slony, and would appreciate all the help that I can get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if all Slony processes are running, or better - restart them. After restarting check the logs, that can be caused sometimes by some DDL query, that was performed by hand on master. If there are some serious errors on slaves, or the lag is not falling down too fast, you could always reinit the replication (but beware, that will delete all data from all tables on the slave databases).

Comment: How do I go about starting slony?

Comment: This is a prod site, should I schedule downtime?

Comment: Also how do i reinit the replication?